# uWSGI unable to load Flask app

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have been poking around on this for a couple days and I am still having issues. My uWSGI instance is apparently not loading my Flask app. I am running a CentOS 7 Vagrant and using Ansible for config mgmt. I will post the final templated files

My file setup is as follows

```
#/etc/tickets/tickets.ini
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi
master = true
processes = 4
socket = tickets.sock
chmod-socket = 664
uid = uwsgi
gid = nginx
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
logto2 = /var/log/uwsgi/tickets.log
```

Module

```
#/opt/tickets/wsgi.py
import os

from create import create_app

app = create_app(os.getenv('APP_CONFIG') or 'default')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Systemd service

```
#/etc/systemd/system/tickets.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve tickets
After=network.target

[Service]
User=uwsgi
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tickets
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/tickets/tickets.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is my apps uwsgi log

```
[vagrant@tickets uwsgi]$ cat tickets.log 

*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:839: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 14820)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 14886, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 14887, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 14888, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 14889, cores: 1)
```

I'm at a loss right now. I've tried moving the `.ini` for the uwsgi into the directory with `wysgi.py` but that didn't work either. `ticket.sock` does get created in the `/opt/tickets` directory. The service is running but it again it appears it is not loading the app.

**EDIT**

Modeled after this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7).